# wso2 ​WSO2 Microservices Framework for Java petstore sample cannot run on ubuntu

Tags: wso2, msf4j

I try to follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/MSS100/Running+as+an+MSA+Application to run petstore sample on ubuntu which is hosted on AWS. 
I met several issues:

1. document is incorrect, it requires to download WSO2 Identity Server.
   Unpack the .zip file and place the  directory in the   `<MSS_HOME>/samples/petstore/deployment/packs` directory. In fact, the
   petstore.sh requires DAS 3.0. Just put wso2das-3.0.0.zip into`<MSS_HOME>/samples/petstore/deployment/packs`. The script will unzip 
   it.
2. kubectl. This script is not put into path, and cause it cannot be
       executed when script changes to another folder.
3. cannot create docker, seems Creating Kube-System Namespace, Kube-DNS, Kube-UI

---

```
error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: EOF
error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: EOF
error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: EOF
error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: EOF
error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the documentation bug. We will fix it. Also please check out the instruction in https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/v1.0.0/samples/petstore/deployment and ensure that all the prerequisites are met.

The docs are at https://docs.wso2.com/display/MSF4J100/Running+as+an+MSA+Application

Comment: In this document, the default vagrant version is 1.4.3. Which source do you add?

Comment: BTW, which source do you use, I cannot install virtualbox by "sudo apt-get install virtualbox"

Comment: oh, I have found virtualbox source

Comment: which version of vagrant do you use? I switch to 1.8.1, it has conflict with bundler

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have done following
export KUBERNETES_MASTER=http://172.17.8.101:8080

Sometimes, if you previously tried out k8s, it will keep previous kubectl configuration under ~/.kube folder. Try removing that folder.

If you have installed some version of kubectl, remove it, otherwise kubectl client and server will not match. run.sh will download compatible kubectl version and install into /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Comment: which version of vagrant do you use? I switch to 1.8.1, it has conflict with bundler

Comment: In my MAC, I'm using 1.7.4.

Comment: I met version conflict error. " could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    vagrant (= 1.7.4) was resolved to 1.7.4, which depends on
      bundler (<= 1.10.5, >= 1.5.2)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.11.2)"  But when I run bundle --version, the bundler version is 1.10.6.  In fact I have run command "gem uninstall bundler" to clean all version, but system always complains that 1.11.2 is current version

Comment: I have checked couple people who used Linux with petstore, they are using 1.8.0 , 1.7.4. It should work with 1.8.1 as well.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? We have tested the script with Ubuntu Desktop14.04 , 15.10. Since you are using AWS ubuntu server, some dependent packages may not install properly for vagrant setup

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty